# .htaccess URL Rewrite Error - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple rewrite rule. My entire .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ company-page.php?company_url=$1
RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ company-page.php?company_url=$1
```

This is perfectly run on locally Wamp server but not working on online server. It display following error.!

```
The requested URL /EZsample/login/mereco-technologies/ was not found on this server.
```

Can anyone help me!

Comment: does your hosting provider allow you to view your virtual host files? did you check your apache virtual host config allows rewrites? do you have ssh access?

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess file and where is `company-page.php` located?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a VPS please use this article,

1.Make sure u have enabled Mod_Rewrite ?
2.Made the changes in the virtual host configurations

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This line of code helped me solve a very similar issue:

```
Options -MultiViews
```